# Сумма значений по полю, отфильтрованные по значениям из каждой строки

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, filter

Как в в каждой строке поля check1 вывести сумму значений поля del_qty, которые совпадают с shipto,plu из датафрейма?

```
         date shipto       plu  del_qty  stock_qty   MTO  check1
0  2017-12-24   1119  16587240      2.0      196.0   4.0       0
1  2017-12-24  25953  16370061      4.0       24.0   3.5       0
2  2017-12-24  25953  16587244      1.0       50.0   7.5       0
3  2017-12-24   6597  16337111      0.0       51.0   5.2       0
4  2017-12-24   6597  16587240     21.0       84.0  17.0       0
5  2017-12-24  25953  16587240     27.0       93.0   9.1       0
6  2017-12-24   6597  16370061      5.0       54.0   4.0       0
7  2017-12-24   1119  16587244      1.0      154.0   5.9       0
8  2017-12-24  25953  16337111      2.0       49.0   1.8       0
9  2017-12-24   6597  16587244     26.0      120.0   8.8       0
10 2017-12-25   6597  16337111      5.0       46.0   4.5       0
11 2017-12-25   1119  16587240      1.0      195.0   2.3       0
12 2017-12-25  25953  16370061      3.0       21.0   1.1       0
13 2017-12-25  25953  16587244      0.0       50.0  17.4       0
14 2017-12-25   6597  16587244      2.0      118.0   9.6       0
15 2017-12-25  25953  16587240     33.0      135.0  15.7       0
16 2017-12-25   6597  16587240     12.0       72.0  15.4       0
17 2017-12-25   1119  16587244      2.0      152.0   9.4       0
18 2017-12-25  25953  16337111      5.0       44.0   3.8       0
19 2017-12-25   6597  16370061      4.0       50.0   3.6       0
20 2017-12-26   6597  16587244      9.0      165.0   9.2       0
21 2017-12-26   6597  16370061      3.0       47.0   5.7       0
22 2017-12-26   6597  16337111      5.0       41.0   3.7       0
23 2017-12-26  25953  16587240     59.0       76.0  20.3       0
24 2017-12-26   1119  16587240      9.0      186.0   2.0       0
25 2017-12-26  25953  16337111      5.0       39.0   1.9       0
26 2017-12-26  25953  16370061      2.0       19.0   2.9       0
27 2017-12-26   1119  16587244      4.0      148.0   7.2       0
28 2017-12-26   6597  16587240      9.0       63.0  16.4       0
29 2017-12-26  25953  16587244      0.0       78.0  20.7       0
```

Т.е. к примеру, в строке 29 в столбце check1 вместо 0 будет сумма значений поля del_qty только тех строк поля shipto, и plu равны shipto, plu текущей строки

Сам датафрейм

```
import pandas
df=pandas.DataFrame([[datetime.date(2017, 12, 24), '1119', 16587240, 2.0, 196.0, 4.0], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 24), '25953', 16370061, 4.0, 24.0, 3.5], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 24), '25953', 16587244, 1.0, 50.0, 7.5], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 24), '6597', 16337111, 0.0, 51.0, 5.2], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 24), '6597', 16587240, 21.0, 84.0, 17.0], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 24), '25953', 16587240, 27.0, 93.0, 9.1], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 24), '6597', 16370061, 5.0, 54.0, 4.0], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 24), '1119', 16587244, 1.0, 154.0, 5.9], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 24), '25953', 16337111, 2.0, 49.0, 1.8], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 24), '6597', 16587244, 26.0, 120.0, 8.8], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 25), '6597', 16337111, 5.0, 46.0, 4.5], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 25), '1119', 16587240, 1.0, 195.0, 2.3], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 25), '25953', 16370061, 3.0, 21.0, 1.1], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 25), '25953', 16587244, 0.0, 50.0, 17.4], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 25), '6597', 16587244, 2.0, 118.0, 9.6], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 25), '25953', 16587240, 33.0, 135.0, 15.7], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 25), '6597', 16587240, 12.0, 72.0, 15.4], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 25), '1119', 16587244, 2.0, 152.0, 9.4], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 25), '25953', 16337111, 5.0, 44.0, 3.8], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 25), '6597', 16370061, 4.0, 50.0, 3.6], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 26), '6597', 16587244, 9.0, 165.0, 9.2], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 26), '6597', 16370061, 3.0, 47.0, 5.7], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 26), '6597', 16337111, 5.0, 41.0, 3.7], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 26), '25953', 16587240, 59.0, 76.0, 20.3], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 26), '1119', 16587240, 9.0, 186.0, 2.0], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 26), '25953', 16337111, 5.0, 39.0, 1.9], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 26), '25953', 16370061, 2.0, 19.0, 2.9], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 26), '1119', 16587244, 4.0, 148.0, 7.2], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 26), '6597', 16587240, 9.0, 63.0, 16.4], [datetime.date(2017, 12, 26), '25953', 16587244, 0.0, 78.0, 20.7]],columns=['date', 'shipto', 'plu', 'del_qty', 'stock_qty', 'MTO'])
df['date']=pandas.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Пробую посчитать сумму каждой выборки:

```
df['check1']=df[((df['shipto']==df['shipto']) & (df['plu']==df['plu']))]['stock_qty'].sum()
```

Но, к сожалению, получаю сумму всех значений столбца del_qty
Пожалуйста, помогите! Сломал всю голову и гугл.
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Приведите пример того что вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: s/отфильтрованные/сгруппированные/

Comment: К примеру в последней строке в столбце **check1** будет сумма строк 2, 13, 29 (т.к. значения полей shipto, plu в них такие же как и в последней строке). В строке 28 эта сумма будет равна 42 (т.к. значения полей shipto, plu в них такие же как и в строке 28

Comment: Тогда (после изменения вопроса) в обоих решениях уберите поле ‘date’ из группировки

Comment: Да! Теперь все заработало. Была ошибка в вопросе! Спасибо.Поясните вкратце, плз, как transform работает в этом случае?

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то здесь может помочь `groupby` метод.

В частности, `df.groupby(by=['date', 'shipto', 'plu'])['del_qty'].sum()`

Comment: благодаря вашему ответу я кажется понял чего хочет автор вопроса :)

Answer (score 2):

```
In [5]: df['check1'] = df.groupby(['shipto','plu'])['del_qty'].transform('sum')

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
         date  shipto       plu  del_qty  stock_qty   MTO  check1
0  2017-12-24    1119  16587240      2.0      196.0   4.0    12.0
1  2017-12-24   25953  16370061      4.0       24.0   3.5     9.0
2  2017-12-24   25953  16587244      1.0       50.0   7.5     1.0
3  2017-12-24    6597  16337111      0.0       51.0   5.2    10.0
4  2017-12-24    6597  16587240     21.0       84.0  17.0    42.0
5  2017-12-24   25953  16587240     27.0       93.0   9.1   119.0
6  2017-12-24    6597  16370061      5.0       54.0   4.0    12.0
7  2017-12-24    1119  16587244      1.0      154.0   5.9     7.0
8  2017-12-24   25953  16337111      2.0       49.0   1.8    12.0
9  2017-12-24    6597  16587244     26.0      120.0   8.8    37.0
..        ...     ...       ...      ...        ...   ...     ...
20 2017-12-26    6597  16587244      9.0      165.0   9.2    37.0
21 2017-12-26    6597  16370061      3.0       47.0   5.7    12.0
22 2017-12-26    6597  16337111      5.0       41.0   3.7    10.0
23 2017-12-26   25953  16587240     59.0       76.0  20.3   119.0
24 2017-12-26    1119  16587240      9.0      186.0   2.0    12.0
25 2017-12-26   25953  16337111      5.0       39.0   1.9    12.0
26 2017-12-26   25953  16370061      2.0       19.0   2.9     9.0
27 2017-12-26    1119  16587244      4.0      148.0   7.2     7.0
28 2017-12-26    6597  16587240      9.0       63.0  16.4    42.0
29 2017-12-26   25953  16587244      0.0       78.0  20.7     1.0

[30 rows x 7 columns]
```

---

`df.groupby(...).transform(<agg_func>)`не уменьшает число строк, т.е. результат аггрегируещей функции присваивается всем строкам группы:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
   grp  val
0    1    1
1    1    2
2    2    3
3    2    4
4    2    5

In [9]: df.groupby('grp').transform('sum')
Out[9]:
   val
0    3
1    3
2   12
3   12
4   12
```

в отличии от `df.groupby(...).agg_func()`:

```
In [10]: df.groupby('grp').sum()
Out[10]:
     val
grp
1      3
2     12
```

Comment: Да, этот способ работает! Спасибо огромное!!!